# Upgrading woes with Linux, C++, Kdevelop, gcc, 64 bit application

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, casting

At work, I've been trying to get a new version of Red Hat Linux installed on a computer, and more importantly, to run a custom bit of code. When I made this upgrade, I noticed the following error:

> cast from 'void*' to 'int' loses precision

In addtion, I've been noticing a string of other errors based from a library which forces use to 32 bit addresses. They seem to result from essentially type casting an in to a custom library 32 bit value.

Bottom line is this. I believe that the compiler has changed the default size of an int from 32 bit to 64 bit. I'm trying to figure out if this is the case without writing a trivial program to determine the size of the integer. In addition, is there a way to force the size back to 32 bits, at least as a proof of concept?

Comment: "*I'm trying to figure out if this is the case without writing a trivial program to determine the size of the integer.*"  I respectfully suggest that you write a trivial program to determine the size of an integer (and a `void*` for that matter.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on an x86_64 box, `int` is still 4 bytes.  if it was 8, the compiler would not tell you

```
cast from 'void*' to 'int' loses precision
```

because there would be no precision to lose.  what it's telling you that your trying to cram an 8byte pointer to a 4byte int, that's quite obviously going to lose a bit of information.

also, and this is just a sidenote, how hard can it be to write this?

```
#include <ostream>
#include <iostream>

#define sz(t) std::cout << sizeof(t) << '\n'
int
main(void)
{
  sz(char);
  sz(int);
  sz(long);
  sz(void*);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-m32` [`gcc`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc) switch.

Try compiling this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    long z;
    printf("size is %ld\n", sizeof(z));
    return 0;
}
```

With `-m32` you should get `4`, with `-m64` you should get `8`.

Comment: but his compiler complains about `void*` to `int` conversion, not `void*` to `long`.  i think it's safe to assume that he's on an x86_64 machine, `int` is 32bit, `void*`, begin a pointer, 64bit.

Comment: @justsomebody: I'm just answering his question on how to force the compiler to compile in 32-bit mode. And I used `long` in the example because this way he can easily confirm what his compiler uses as default -- `long` on a 64-bit machine will be `8`.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: http://ideone.com/UymsS. I also tested on my 64-bit machine using `-m32` and it gave `4` as well.

Answer (score 0):

After much toil, I was able to figure out the following.

1. My previous code was needing to get a 32 bit custom integer from a pointer in memory, due to a trick of addressing spaces. Bottom line is, the compiler in Redhat 4 allowed it, but not in Redhat 5. The solution was to convert it first to a 64 bit standart integer, then to a 32 bit , like this `(int32)(int64)some_pointer_value`. I couldn't find a better solution, but this seemed to work.
2. There was a few switch statements with long cases. The new compiler didn't seem to like that. A quick rearranging of code seemed to fix it.
3. The intptr_t trick worked quite well.
4. There was a few class functions that were declared like `class_name::function1(){...}`. I think I must have picked up that habit from anther programming language. The `class_name::` had to go, but once it did, the code compiled.

Once I did all of these things, then the code compiled. Furthermore, it worked just the same in Redhat 4. Whew!